# Sublime Text 3 command: convert_special_characters on iMac

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I have a cool function on my Sublime Text on Windows that's "wraps" the selected text into a HTML Tag.
(Example .gif)
[Sublime convert_special_characters command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgmIV.gif)

On my Sublime Text in Mac, I can't do the same thing.

Am I missing something? I've installed all the packages included on my Windows PC. And also tested other Key bindings (they all work, except from the "convert_special_characters" command).

On my Key Binding Settings I've set
`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+g"], "command": "convert_special_characters" }`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.
I've deleted and reinstalled the **Emmet** plugin.
Also discovered what file was not working on the plugin and changed it.
The file was located in

```
AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Emmet.sublime-package
```

If anyone needs the file, I'll be happy to share.